# There is no styling of nested lists

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, design

The style for nested lists is the same as the styling of a simple list. The biggest problem with this is the bottom margin:

> - A
>
>   - A → 1
>   - A → 2
>   - A → 3
> - B
>
>   - B → 1
>   - B → 2
>
>     - B → 2 → X
>     - B → 2 → Y
>     - B → 2 → Z
>   - B → 3
> - C
>
>   - C → 1
>   - C → 2
>   - C → 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straight from Google Chrome's user agent stylesheets:

```
ol ol ul,
ol ul ul,
ul ol ul,
ul ul ul
{
    list-style-type: square;
}

ol ul,
ul ol,
ul ul,
ol ol
{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

ul ul,
ol ul
{
    list-style-type: circle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, how to fix in CSS?

Comment: See my answer. Did you know that finger nails grow three times faster than toe nails? (Just getting past the 15 characters minimum requirement)

Comment: excellent, very helpful, will implement -- thank you!